Getting s3:GetObject AccessDenied error when trying to use AWS Sagemaker built-in model retrieval
I'm trying to train a LightGBM model using AWS Sagemaker built-in model.
The following code (copy&pasted from AWS docs) runs into an s3:GetObject Access Denied error. It is likely that my IAM role is not sufficiently equipped with permissions. The question is, what bucket does it want access to?
If I want to stay in the realms of least privilege, I need to set the exact bucket (-pattern) which I need access to in order to retrieve the built-in models and scripts, and cannot use wildcard.
train_source_uri = script_uris.retrieve(
  model_id=train_model_id,
  model_version=train_model_version,
  script_scope=train_scope,
)


To answer my own question:
The requested bucket in my region (eu-central-1) is called arn:aws:s3:::jumpstart-cache-prod-eu-central-1.
I temporarily used a wildcard to make the call to script_uris.retrieve work and limited the access to the returned bucket.
